# Implementing a threshold for multiclass classification with softmax activation

Tags: conv-neural-network, threshold

We have a CNN where images are classified into between 7 and 30 classes, depending on the training set. The final output is via SoftMax activation, and thus all the probabilities add to one.

I notice that often some unseen image triggers a high probability for one class, even when it looks nothing like the typical image from that class. I infer that the some feature from that class has responded just a little to that image, but not for anyother classes, and SoftMax has amped up the probabilities so they add to one.

While we make an effort to try to cover all variations of images in the training set, some classes have such huge variation that this is impossible. So I would like to put a threshold on the probabilities, so that we can filter out some of the low-confidence false detections. How does one do this? Threshold on the input into the SoftMax layer instead of the output? Some other kind of measure?